# TTS remaining null

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apache, import

TTS object tts is always remaining `null`.
`onInit` always shows the toast message failed.
I have tried all other methods of creating onInitlistener as a separate method.
But the status code of onInit always remains `-1` ie the value of error.
Please Help!!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSpeechButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.speechButton);
    mSpeechButton.setEnabled(false);
    mSpeechTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speechText);
    // Hide the ActionBar
    getActionBar().hide();
    tts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
                mSpeechButton.setEnabled(true);
                mTrue = true;
            } else {
                mTrue = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
    mSpeechButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

Comment: try to replace getApplicationContext() with your activity context

Comment: working code may be something wrong http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_text_to_speech.htm

Comment: @Meenal I tried changing the context. Still when I run the application , it says failed initializing tts .

Comment: are you getting any error..post your logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   package com.example.textspeech;

   import java.util.Locale;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;

   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextToSpeech mTextToSpeech;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTextToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(),
            new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInit(int status) {
                    mTextToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                    mTextToSpeech.speak("You will use Eclipse IDE to create an Android application and name it as TextToSpeech under a package", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }
            });
}
```

}